# How to prevent a user from manipulating query string in URL?

Tags: php, html

Say I have a website like `foo.com` and have the user be able to enter the username, and gives you back your `view` count. So if the `username` is `bar`, the url would look something like `foo.com/index.php?username="bar"`.

Now if I had another user `john`, what could prevent `bar` from entering `foo.com/index.php?username="bar"` and getting their `view` count?

Comment: Does the user have any form of authentication - simply logging in should be enough (with validation of the request against the logged in user)

Comment: If a user should only be allowed be view their own data then you need some form of authentication. Usually a username/pwd is used to identify a single user. This user's information is stored in a session so any request "knows" who this user is and you can then retrieve their information/view count/whatever.

Comment: You can't just use the concept of sending plain username in the query parameter, simply you can't, replace it with session

Comment: @NigelRen I'm using `$_POST` and what not, but I have AJAX calls for getting non-sensitive data. I was just wondering if there's any way to block that.

Comment: Your question seems not to be regarding coding. Please ask it on another platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what could prevent bar from entering foo.com/index.php?username="bar" and getting their view count?

The short answer is nothing. Cause there are no safe (and consistent along different browsers and systems) ways to prevent user from editing the url. But...
You can check if the current logged in user has the permissions to view that data.

If you're using a framework, probably there's already an implementation for RBAC (Role Based Access Control).
So you should check the documentation for that.

If you're not and you're on a project with plain PHP, you have to implement that. And it can get quite complicated.

This is one of the downsides of PHP, user can always alter the request (and the forms contents) and you should always check that the data is correct. (that's one of the reasons most PHP programmers use frameworks).